# Error not resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Following run time error is coming:

```
javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config
```

Caused by:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException - javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.Config
```

I have also downloaded `jstl-1.2.jar` and `jsp-api-2.0.jar` file still above error is not resolving. So please help me...

Comment: You would need `servlet-api.jar`.

Comment: Please provide code, i mean what you are trying to do when this exception is occuring

Comment: Add standard-1.1.2 and jstl-1.2.jar in your lib

Comment: did you added those jars to the classpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first check that you IDE accolumate your project and coppy all liblriry in startUp folder. Very often users foregot that.

and check that you have this jar
maven

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.jar` file.

[Download from here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavaxservletjspjstljar.htm) and include it in your project class path.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion but still unknown error occured:  HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.43

Comment: @Marmikkansara It means your first problem of `ClassNotFoundException` has been resolved by adding this jar. Therefore now you should accept this answer as it will help other users on this site facing same issue. To accept an answer just click on the left side Right Tick sign of the answer.

Comment: @Marmikkansara As far as your new problem is concerned, there can be several reasons for it. If you need help you can post a new question with the Full Stacktrace and some code, so that we could find out why this is happening.